# PHP Array Help, explode

Tags: php, arrays

I am stuck and was hoping someone could help me out.

I have a multiple selection list that looks like this:

```
<select name='verseData[]' size=5 multiple>
    <option value='pig:oink'>Pig
    <option value='duck:quack'>Duck
    <option value='cow:moo'>Cow
    <option value='sheep:baa'>Sheep
    <option value='horse:neigh'>Horse
    <option value='dog:woof'>Dog
    <option value='cat:meow'>Cat
    <option value='rooster:cock-a-doodle-doo'>Rooster
```

I want to separate the animal and animal noise.  I also want to be able to refer to them so that you could write a sentence using to variables like:

The $animal makes the sound $noise.

The dog makes the sound woof.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you already said it, `explode`

Comment: I am getting the selection from the form with $selected=$_REQUEST['verseData']; Then I try to use explode by referring to the array $selected and it says that it needs to be a string?

Comment: What code did you use to explode the array??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    foreach($_POST['verseData'] as $value){
        list($animal, $noise) = explode(":", $value);
        echo "The $animal makes the sound $noise";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you explode the string into array. once you explode they will get the numeric index starting from 0 and incremented by 1 for every element.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['verseData']))
{
   $selected = $_REQUEST['verseData'];
   $explode = explode(":", $selected);

   echo "$explode[0] makes the sound $explode[1]";


}
```

As per comment above in your question you need to change the from `name="verseData[]"` to `name="verseData"`